# What happens when the God King is defeated?

Tags: infinity-blade

I'm having difficulties with the boss known as the God King in Infinity Blade. Since I'm struggling to beat him, my question is: what happens after you defeat him? I'm not asking for tips on how to defeat him.

Answer (score 7):

Spoiler:

> When you defeat the God King, he explains that he was the only thing stopping creatures even more powerful than he from coming after you. This sets up for the additional chapters planned, where you delve into the dungeons of the castle to fight the Titans.

Additional spoiler:

> After the credits roll, there's an additional cutscene where you find a control panel on the God-King's throne that activates a hologram of a planet with a shattered moon orbiting around it. The character advancement screen then appears, and the next bloodline begins. You don't find out anything more about the hologram.

Video spoilers:

> See the [ending](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YFUu66_5m0&feature=related) and the [after-credits cutscene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bq1IKwfc5Vg&feature=related) on YouTube.

Also, you get an achievement.

Answer (score 1):

there are other strong opponents to kill once you get the infinity blade.

Answer (score 0):

Once you defeat the God King, you don't get the Infinity Blade.  It's now in the store, so you can buy it for 100,000 gold or more.  I've just killed the God King, and it gave me a sword called "Ember" instead of the Infinity Blade.

Comment: The Ember sword would've just been a random item drop, not that you will get it everytime you beat him.